# Hadoop test BenchmarkThroughput crashes with NullPointerException due to mapred.temp.dir

Tags: java, hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I just configured Eclipse with the development environment for Hadoop(v 1.0.1). When I run one of the tests `/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/BenchmarkThroughput.java` it crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

The problem seems to be in `BenchmarkThroughput.run()`, line 196 where it does `System.setProperty("test.build.data", localDir)`. The `localDir` shows up as `null` because `mapred.temp.dir` is not set.

How should I correct this problem? Should I set the value of `mapred.temp.dir` in core-site.xml or is there a problem in the way I configured Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are able to start the namenode. Run start-all and check the log. most probably it is not running.